# use phonon crash in phonon_ds9d4.dll

Tags: qt, crash, phonon

use code :

```
Phonon::VideoPlayer *player = new Phonon::VideoPlayer(Phonon::MusicCategory, NULL);
QObject::connect(player, SIGNAL(finished()), player, SLOT(deleteLater()));
player->play(Phonon::MediaSource("c:/yaodong.mkv"));
```

but crash.
env is win7 and vs2008, qt 4.7.1
windows sdk is 7.1
dx sdk is Microsoft DirectX SDK (March 2009)
and i find the stack is 
mediaobject.cpp (line 233) graph is null

```
            } else if (!m_currentWork.url.isEmpty()) {
                //let's render a url (blocking call)
                hr = m_currentWork.graph->RenderFile(reinterpret_cast<const wchar_t *>(m_currentWork.url.utf16()), 0);
            }
```

then i find run step to the function:

```
   quint16 WorkerThread::addUrlToRender(const QString &url)
    {
        QMutexLocker locker(&m_mutex);
        Work w;
        w.task = Render;
        //we create a new graph
        w.graph = Graph(CLSID_FilterGraph, IID_IGraphBuilder);
        w.url = url;
        w.url.detach();
        w.id = m_currentWorkId++;
        m_queue.enqueue(w);
        m_waitCondition.set();
        return w.id;
    }
```

the line : w.graph = Graph(CLSID_FilterGraph, IID_IGraphBuilder);
w.graph is null.

but i wrote the code outside :

```
IGraphBuilder *pGraph = NULL;
::CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph, 0, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IGraphBuilder,
    reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pGraph));
```

the pGraph is not null.

help. thanks!

Comment: i reinstall qt can not run successfully , too

Comment: solution!it is other software register some com interface(about ffdshow.dll) in my pc. uninstall the software and unregister the com interface about the software. reregister the related com object.